# How to set time zone in code in a Firebase Cloud Function v2 scheduled function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

In Firebase Cloud Functions v1, configuring the time zone for scheduled functions could be done in the function's signature.

```
exports.v1ScheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule("every day 00:00")
                                              .timeZone("Etc/GMT+12")
                                              .onRun(async (context) => {
    ...
});
```

However, with the syntax changes in v2, this changes.

```
exports.v2ScheduledFunction = onSchedule("every day 00:00", async (event) => {
    ...
});
```

The documentation says that v2 can take Unix Crontab and App Engine syntax for the string schedule. However, I don't think you can specify time zone in either Unix Crontab or App Engine syntax. Is there a way to specify time zone for scheduled functions in v2 in code? If not, how can it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.scheduler.md#scheduleronschedule), the first parameter is either a schedule or a [`scheduler.ScheduleOptions`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.scheduler.scheduleoptions) object. FYI: This options object can also contain options in [`GlobalOptions`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.globaloptions.md#globaloptions_interface) (`secrets`, `region`, etc.).

To specify a time zone, you would use:

```js
exports.v2ScheduledFunction = onSchedule(
  {
    schedule: "every day 00:00",
    timeZone: "Etc/GMT+12"
  },
  async (event) => {
    // your function code
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the documentation it doesn't seem possible to add the timezone unless you can ssh into the firebase server and run custom commands to change the computer local timezone.

Comment: The question isn't asking how to set the timezone of the server instance.  It's asking how to set the timezone of the scheduler that determines what time to run the function.